# Connectivity of the space of $l_p^n$s

Tags: normed-spaces

Is it known whether the space $\{ l_p^n : 1 < p < \infty\}$ is connected with the topology induced by Banach-Mazur distance?
As stated in a comment, this would follow from a bound on the operator norm of the identity matrix mapping $l_p^n$ to $l_q^n$ in terms of $|p-q|$, so my question becomes: What is the operator norm of the identity matrix mapping $l_p^n$ to $l_q^n$?

Comment: I think you can prove that the map from p to l_p^n is continuous... So yes would follow from the fact that continuous maps preserve connectivity. All you would need to do is control the operator norm of the identity matrix when you go from Lp to Lq in terms of |p - q|, since this will give an upper bound on the Banach Mazur distance. I haven't checked my work on this, so maybe I'm missing something.